# confused with certificates and profiles adhoc distribution

Tags: ios

I have a number of apps already uploaded on Apple Store. I now want to use adhoc distribution to some of them, and in some of them also include push notifications.

I am having a production certificate already, since these apps are already installed.

My questions are:

1. In order to add adhoc distribution, I need to create a new adhoc provisioning profile that needs to be matched with one certificate. Should this be my production or request a new certificate, then create a new SSL certificate and so on and match this one with the adhoc provisioning profile.
2. The same questions applies for the pus notification.  A different profile will be created but how about the certificate?

So, in general my questions is: Do I have only one active production certificate which matches with the unique profiles or not?

So far, where I hadn't included any adhoc or APNS service I had only one and I do not how this changes right  now.

Answer (score 0):

It's all the same certificate (the one you already have).